# Displays which can downscale resolution with keeping physical pixels

Tags: display, resolution

I'm seeking for displays which are able to downscale resolution without loosing image quality.

As an example, considering a `1920x1080` display, if I'd set the resolution to `640x480`, I'd like to see a `640x480` pixel brick in the middle, and black pixels around in all four directions. As opposed to this, those displays which I've seen would enlarge the image to fit the screen, so loosing the 1:1 physical-to-logical pixel ratio.

Are there any displays on the market which are known to be able to do this kind of downscaling?

Comment: Yes. You will just have to check the scaling/interpolation options that are available for each model. There are various displays that support [1:1 mode](http://www.prad.de/en/monitore/shownews_lex82.html).

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing out the technical term for this, I'll have a look. If you could put this into an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: your gpu could support 1:1 output even if your monitor doesn't. you may want to check your control software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various displays that support a [1:1 mode](http://www.prad.de/en/monitore/shownews_lex82.html) as one of their "Interpolation modes". So essentially they will display the original resolution and not really interpolate at all. Other options would be to scale according to the aspect ratio etc.. As it depends on the individual display which modes are supported, you will have to check the manual/description of displays that interest you.

I do know that some at least some Fujitsu displays support it. In addition to a interpolation mode (keept aspect ratio, 1:1/native, full screen, zoomed etc.) your probably need a display that also supports your resolution (`640x480`) for interpolation. So it might be worth it to first check for displays that support the resolution and afterwards for whenever they also support a interpolation mode that fits your needs.